# What is the best way to deploy a Python Flask application along with a ReactJS application?

Tags: python, reactjs, flask, deployment, windows-server-2012

I have developed two applications, one ReactJS, and one Python using Flask. The development was for ReactJS only at first, but then I created the Flask app to use it to write to files on server, and run batch files. I am getting the data from an API that belongs to another application. The Flask app is the only app to communicate with the API, while the React app gets the data to display by sending to Flask. Also using a Flask app as a middle agent made the CORS issue go away so far.

No the question is, what is the best practice to deploy on windows server under current circumstances? I searched and found that I have two options, IIS and Apache. I never deployed any application before other that on Heroku, so I'm far from familiar with the task.

Comment: try to ask [here](https://devops.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 0):

I made my reactjs app a static single-page-app (`npm run build` ) and hosted the js files through a custom flask endpoint.
This may not be an option for you though in which case you can configure apache (or iis) to host both flask (with mod_wsgi) and proxy nodejs react.
You can also run both sites on a different port or vhost but then you may have to configure CORS.